# Why does my Firestore query requires this specific ordering of fields of the index?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this query to Firestore:

```
const query = await firestore.collection(`/records`)
        .where("targetId", "==", someId)
        .where("location", "==", someLocation)
        .where("dayCode", ">=", domeDay);
```

When run, it asks for an index: `location ASC, targetId ASC, dayCode ASC`
I already have the same index but with fields in different order, so in order to try and re-use it, *I re-order my query, but it still asks for the same specific ordering.*
Why does this query requires this specific ordering in fields of the index?

Comment: Please, share your Firestore data and index configuration. Moreover, I'd try using `firestore.collection('records')` (without the leading `/`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To be clear: I have no issue with the query, it works well, the index also. I am asking why does the index needs this specific ordering: ```location, targetId, dayCode```, and not ```targetId, location, dayCode```

Comment: What specific index do you already have that you'd expect Firestore to use to fulfill this query?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I previously had ```targetId Ascending dayCode Ascending location Ascending```

Comment: That index won't be enough. Essentially: Firestore needs to have an index, where it can find the starting point of the results with a immediately lookup (no index scanning), and where it can then return the results as a single stream from that start location. So you'll definitely need an index where `dayCode` is last in there, as you have a range condition on that. If you have an index on `location, targetId, location, dayCode ASC` Firestore **may** be able to use that as it can possibly reverse the `==` conditions. I'm not completely sure if it does this though, hence won't post an answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful insight: "return the results as a single stream from that start location". Indeed it looks like Firestore re-orders the conditions, I wondered about the logic behind this re-ordering, maybe alphabetical in order to maximize index reuse, or maybe depending on the index shape to maximize retrieval speed...